# Does $\mathrm{Im}(f(z))$ bounded above $\implies$ $|f|$ is bounded, for analytic $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

If $f$ is analytic on $\Omega$ s.t. $\mathrm{Im}(f(z))$ is bounded from above, then does this imply that $|f|$ is itself bounded?

I know that if $\Omega = \mathbb{C}$, then the result follows as a result of Liouvilles's Theorem; however, I'm here looking at an arbitrary $\Omega$ that isn't necessarily equal to $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Let $\Omega = \{z \in \Bbb C : |\operatorname{Im}(z)| < 1\}$, $f(z) = z$. Obviously $\operatorname{Im}(f(z))$ is bounded on $\Omega$, but $|f(z)|$ isn't.

Comment: Oh, so easy! I would at least have mapped the disk to a suitable half plane ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Feel free to add it as another example. :)